# Neural Network layer design

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I am kind of new to neural network. This is one piece of code I've tried in Matlab

```
P= 0 + (rand(1) * 10);
T = (P-1)/(P+1);
net = newelm(P,T,5);
net = train(net,P,T);
Y = sim(net,P);
```

Now when I type net.B{1} and net.LW{1} in the command window of matlab, I get the bias weights and layer weights, but I also find that these weight values keep changing according to input values.

So can I have a predefined weight value, the one that doesn't change, for a particular function(and for any value of input), such that using these weight values I can design a neural network for a particular function. Like here I have T which is related to P by a particular equation.

Answer (score 0):

If one of your inputs has a known relation to the output variable, take it out of the network instead of creating a complex workaround like fixing network weights. (It *will* be complex because of the variable interactions and nonlinear transformations inside the network.)

E.g.

```
Y = a*X1 + 3.6*X2  # relationship between Y and X2 is known
```

Then use neural network on this relation:

```
Y - 3.6*X2 = a*X1
^^^^^^^^^^   ^^^^
[target]     [input]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I doubt whether u got my ques. In the code that i have written above, for a particular value of P i get T which has the relation with P given above. Now when i try to read the weights, its different for different P which is obvious. Now is there any chance that i can get constant weight values, say for a particular function, i.e whether for addition or subtraction function, can I have a particular set of weights in a network with which when I give 2 inputs to that network, I get the sum or difference of those two inputs if its an addition or subtraction function.